# Uncaught ReferenceError: createFFmpeg is not defined

Tags: javascript, html, ffmpeg

How to create an FFMpeg video tag in HTML 5?

I get this error

> Uncaught ReferenceError: createFFmpeg is not defined

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>HTML5 FFmpeg Example</title>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@ffmpeg/ffmpeg"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <h1>HTML5 FFmpeg Example</h1>
  <video controls>
      <source src="input.mp4" />
  </video>
  <script>
    const ffmpeg = createFFmpeg({ log: true });
    const loadFFmpeg = async () => {
      await ffmpeg.load();
      console.log('FFmpeg loaded');
    };
    loadFFmpeg();
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: @mplungjan I get this error `Uncaught ReferenceError: FFmpeg is not defined`

Comment: @mplungjan `Uncaught ReferenceError: FFmpeg is not defined`

Comment: what documentation are you following for the code you've written? Doesn't look anything like the examples given by the author

Comment: @JaromandaX  I want to write a simple example so that no one can download the video. How can I do it?

Comment: follow the documentation for the ffmpeg package you're trying to use - you're using version 0.11.x syntax, but downloading version 0.12.x - check https://ffmpegwasm.netlify.app/docs/migration

Comment: also note the documentation states that *As @ffmpeg/ffmpeg spawns a web worker, you cannot import @ffmpeg/ffmpeg from CDN like unpkg. It is recommended to download it and host it on your server most of the time.*

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/256419/discussion-between-irankhostravi-and-jaromanda-x).

Answer (score 0):

Please refer a ffmpeg Official Documentation . Because createFFmpeg Function in that Library you are using.
Thanks.